# C++ access private class member

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ Class with provides a pool of buffers. The class contains the actual (private) pool and a public function with return a pointer to a free buffer. The class declaration is within a hpp file.

**CTransmissionBuffers.hpp**

```
class CTransmissionBuffers {
    public: 
        static constexpr uint32_t buffer_length = 1000;
        struct Transmissionbuffer_T
        {
            osMutexId mutex;                
            uint8_t data[buffer_length];    
            osThreadId thread_id;           
        };

        CTransmissionBuffers();
        virtual ~CTransmissionBuffers();

        static bool Init_Transmission_Buffers();
        static Transmissionbuffer_T* Get_New_Transmission_Buffer();     
        static void Free_Transmission_Buffer(Transmissionbuffer_T* pBuffer);

    private:
        static constexpr uint32_t n_buffer = 3;
        static Transmissionbuffer_T buffer_pool[n_buffer];
};
```

**CTransmissionBuffers.cpp**

```
#include <CTransmissionBuffers.hpp>



CTransmissionBuffers::Transmissionbuffer_T buffer_pool[CTransmissionBuffers::n_buffer] = {}; /// this causes the problem

    CTransmissionBuffers::CTransmissionBuffers()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    CTransmissionBuffers::~CTransmissionBuffers()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
    }

    bool CTransmissionBuffers::Init_Transmission_Buffers()
    {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n_buffer; i++)
        {
            buffer_pool[i].mutex = osMutexCreate(nullptr);

            if (nullptr == buffer_pool[i].mutex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    CTransmissionBuffers::Transmissionbuffer_T* CTransmissionBuffers::Get_New_Transmission_Buffer()
    {
        Transmissionbuffer_T* pBuffer = nullptr;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n_buffer; i++)
        {
            if (osOK == osMutexWait(buffer_pool[i].mutex, 0))
            {
                //Mutex  erhalten
                pBuffer = &(buffer_pool[i]);
                break;
            }

        }

        return pBuffer;
    }


    void CTransmissionBuffers::Free_Transmission_Buffer(Transmissionbuffer_T* pBuffer)
    {
        if(nullptr == pBuffer)
        {
            return;
        }
        osMutexRelease(pBuffer->mutex);
    }
```

After compiling this I got a undefined reference to buffer_pool, so I tried to add a

```
CTransmissionBuffers::Transmissionbuffer_T buffer_pool[CTransmissionBuffers::n_buffer] = {};
```

to the corresponding cpp file but a can't access n_buffer because it's private :(

Do I have to define a static member? Do you have some good ideas how to solve this problem?

Greets Julian

Comment: Did you include your .hpp file in your .cpp file?

Comment: `Transmissionbuffer_T` doesn't appear to be a member of `CTransmissionBuffers`.  Did you mean `Transmissionbuffer_T CTransmissionBuffers::buffer_pool[CTransmissionBuffers::n_buffer] = {}`?  Because that [works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1b4bf9f0118d7f8).

Comment: Yes, you have to define a static member. You haven’t shown your cop file, so nobody can tell you what’s wrong.

Comment: perhaps this would be a good time to refer when [static](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static#1) is appropriate in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off.  Transmissionbuffer_T is not a member of your class, but is the type of a member of your class.  A static definition should look like this:

```
Transmissionbuffer_T CTransmissionBuffers::buffer_pool[CTransmissionBuffers::n_buffer]={};
```

In C++17 you can use an inline variable as a more convenient way to work around this issue:

```
class CTransmissionBuffers {
//...
private:
//...
            inline static Transmissionbuffer_T buffer_pool[n_buffer];
}
```

If you declare it an inline variable, do *not* also declare the variable in the outside the class or you'll have duplicate definitions and get an error.

Note: constexpr static members are implicitly inline, so don't need to do anything for n_buffer to work correctly.

Comment: I'm using c++17 but when I'm placing an inline before my variable in my header file i'm getting a compilation error
`class CTransmissionBuffers {

//....
private:
//....
static constexpr uint32_t n_buffer = 3;
inline static Transmissionbuffer_T buffer_pool[n_buffer];
 `
The resulting error is:
`error: 'buffer_pool' declared as an 'inline' field`

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Are you SURE you are actually running it with c++17 mode enabled?  It may also be the case that your compiler doesn't support inline variables yet.

Answer (score 0):

after doing some reasearch it turns out that inline variables are only supported with gcc 7
(see https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)
I'm stuck with gcc6 however.

I initialised the buffers by placing a

```
CTransmissionBuffers::Transmissionbuffer_T CTransmissionBuffers::buffer_pool[n_buffer] = {};
```

at the beginning of the cpp file. That seams to work. Thanks alot for your help :)